# Properties of Grothendieck ring for field of characterictic $p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, grothendieck-rings, virtual-motives

In [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204306) there is a proof that for field $k$ of characteristic zero Grothendieck ring $K(\mathbf{Var}_k)$ is not an integral domain. In many articles I found statement that similar theorem for field of characteristic $p$ is unknown. These articles have at least five years. My question is : Are there some new developments in this area ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Vec" here?

Comment: Sorry, it should be $\mathbf{Var}$ - category of quasi-projective varieties over given field $k$.